# How to save Xml file to pptx file after editing it in python?

Tags: python, xml, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to change some values in pptx file. For that I have converted the pptx file into xml file and changed the value using below code. But I don't know how can I save this new file as an pptx file. I can save it as an xml file but not as pptx. I am using python version 3.10

```
with open('filename.xml','r') as f:
     a = f.read()
     f.closed
if 'value' in a:
     a = a.replace('value', 'newvalue')
print('success')
if 'newvalue' in a:
     print('done')
with open(filename.xml','w') as file:
     print('this works')
     file.write(a)
     print('this worked')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. I would load the input pptx and apply transforms - using python-pptx - to that. Then write out the resulting pptx.

Your example seemed to me to be doing text replacement. That can be done by iterating over the shape objects within the slides - with python-pptx.

Comment: I tried that too. But the pptx file has lot of different shapes and finding shape and replacing text has much more complexity than using xml file to change.

Comment: If you have a code to replace the text, then it would be very much appriciated.

Comment: Actually I don't. How is this more complex than navigating the shapes object on each slide?